# What's wrong with my code? C

Tags: c

I've tried to make a trivia game. 
For some reason, after the first answer, the whole code prints itself when it's only supposed to print only one line at the time.

```
int main()
```

{

```
    char answer;
    int score = 16;


    printf("Hello and welcome to Chen's trivia!\n");
    printf("Press ENTER to continue!\n");
    getchar();

    printf("Ready? Let's begin!\n");
    printf("Press ENTER to continue!\n");
    getchar();


    printf(" Who is the president of the united states?\n");
    printf("Barack Obama, Donald Trump, George w. Bush\n");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
        if(answer == 'Trump' || 'trump'){
        printf("You are correct\n");
        score*=2;
        printf("your score is: %d \n", score);
    }else{
        score = (score / 2);
    printf("Wrong answer!\n");
    printf("score: %d \n", score);
    }


    printf("What superhero shoots web out of his arms?\n");
    printf("A.Batman, B.Spiderman, C.Captain America, D.Superman\n");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    if(answer == 'B' || 'b'){
        printf("That's right, Hero!\n");
        score*=2;
        printf("Youre score is: %d \n", score);
    }else{
    score = (score / 2);
    printf("sorry, wrong answer!\n");
    printf("your score is! %d\n", score);
    }

    printf("Who is the the main character in 'The Matrix'? \n");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    if(answer == 'neo' || 'NEO'){
            score*=2;
        printf("That's right!\n");
        printf("Your score is %d\n", score);
    }else{
        score = (score / 2);
    printf("Sorry, Wrong answer!\n");
    }

    printf("What is the capital of Israel?");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
    if(answer== ('jerusalem') || ('Jerusalem') ){
            score*=2;
        printf("That's right!");
        printf("Your score is:%d", score);
    }else{
        score = (score / 2);
    printf("Sorry, wrong answer!");
    printf("Your score is now:%d", score);
    }


return 0;
```

}

Any ideas? :(
BTW, i'm getting this error on my code:blocks

warning: character constant too long for its type
warning: multi-character character constant wmultichar

got 6 warnings in total.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly compare strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: Also, don't use single quotes around string literals in C.

Comment: Read lines......

Comment: You seem to be aware of the fact that string literals in C use `"..."` quotes. What were you tryng to achieve by using `'` in `'neo'` and `'jerusalem'` then?

Comment: Declare, answer as a char array, like this: `char answer[32];`, and use strcmp or strcasecmp to compare strings, like this:  `if(strcasecmp(answer, "Trump") == 0){`

Answer (score 1):

```
char answer;
/* ... */
scanf(" %c", &answer);

if(answer == 'Trump' || 'trump'){  /* et cetera */
```

You are confusing characters and strings.  A string is an array of
characters.  `%c` is the scanf code for reading a single character; for
a string you would use `%s`.  Character literals are written with single quotes, like `'a'`.   String literals use double quotes: `"A string"`.   You can use
the `==` operator to compare characters, but to compare strings, you should use the `strcmp()` function.

Your usage of the `||` operator doesn't do what you think it does.  You need to write two separate tests:

```
if ( (answer == 'A') || (answer == 'a')) { /* etc */
```